# How reliable is "order" in queried NodeLists

Tags: javascript, html, dom, w3c, specifications

I am wondering about this topic for quite a while. The methods in question are the following:

- `getElementsByTagName`
- `getElementsByClassName`
- `getElementsByName`
- `querySelectorAll`

As far as I know, those DOM methods are the only methods which are able to return frozen or live `NodeLists`. For some of those methods, order is defined by *W3C spec*. For instance, http://www.w3.org writes the following for `NodeLists` returned by `querySelectorAll`

> The querySelectorAll() methods on the Document, DocumentFragment, and
>   Element interfaces must return a NodeList containing all of the
>   matching Element nodes within the subtrees of the context node, in
>   document order. If there are no matching nodes, the method must return
>   an empty NodeList.

However, I couldn't find similar **clear** specifications for the the other methods I mentioned. My questions here are:

- *is there a defined order (most likely document order) for the results* ?
- *how reliable and cross-browser implemented are those specs* ?

---

To be absolute clear:

```
<div>this</div>
<div>is</div>
<div>a demo</div>

// is this always guaranteed to be "<div>is</div>"
document.querySelectorAll('div')[1]
```

Comment: Irrespective of if/how it is defined in the spec, imagine if there was no guaranteed order. Indexed references would have no meaning, would have been abandoned long ago, and everyone would recursively walk through all `childNodes` in the DOM whenever an index guarantee is needed. I've seen nothing to indicate to indicate any variation WRT the order of results.

Comment: ...variation in *which* elements are returned is a different story.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#nodelist), `NodeList`s should be sorted in tree order.

Comment: thats good to know, then the question still open is how good this was implemented by the various browsers and versions.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. All of them are in document order / tree order.

- `getElementsByName` ([DOM Level-2-HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259)) returns a `NodeList`
- `querySelectorAll` ([Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall)) returns a `NodeList` "in document order"
- `getElementsByTagName` ([DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbytagname)) returns a `HTMLCollection`
- `getElementsByClassName` ([DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname)) returns a `HTMLCollection`

[`HTMLCollection`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection) and [`NodeList`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodelist) are both specified to have

> the elements are sorted in [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order).

when those are accessed via indizes.

I think that those specs (even though the linked versions might be newer than some implementations) are reliably implemented by all browsers, mostly because tree order is the most logical and easy-to-code one. Yet, you might need to watch out that some browsers might return lists consisting of *different elements* because their matching of nodes differs. I could think of some quirks when determining the `name` of an element.

Comment: so that is how it "should be" then. What about the realworld implementations ? I actually need to know how reliably that is across a wide range of browser and versions (mobile and desktop)

Comment: I have no statistics and can only guess, but I've never heard of browsers differing from it. The big ones do it correct for sure.

Comment: For which algorithm do you need to know the correct order for sure, btw?