# document order for DOM selection method

Tags: javascript

I know that live NodeList returned by `getElementsByTagName` preserves the document order of elements.

Is it true for `getElementsdByClassName`, `getElementsByName` and `querySelectorAll` methods?

does these method also preserve the document order?

Any DOM/HTML5  W3C standard link would be appreciated.

Comment: exact duplicate of [How reliable is "order" in queried NodeLists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102517/how-reliable-is-order-in-queried-nodelists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All of them are in document order / tree order.

- `getElementsByName` ([DOM Level-2-HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259)) returns a `NodeList`
- `querySelectorAll` ([Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall)) returns a `NodeList` "in document order"
- `getElementsByTagName` ([DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbytagname)) returns a `HTMLCollection`
- `getElementsByClassName` ([DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname)) returns a `HTMLCollection`

[`HTMLCollection`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection) and [`NodeList`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodelist) are both specified to have

> the elements are sorted in [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order).

when those are accessed via indizes. It does not really matter whether the NodeList is live or not (though of course the actual document order could change in contrast to the one preserved in the static NodeList).

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't all work the same way. Only the `getElementsByTagName` method returns a live collection.

The [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) method returns a `NodeList` object which is a live collection of elements.

The [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) method returns a `NodeList` object which is not a live collection.

The [`getElemendsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) methods returns a [`HTMLCollection` object](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-htmlcollection) which is not a live collection.

(Note that different documentation for `getElemenetsByName` specifies either a `HTMLCollection` or a `NodeList`.)

Comment: thanks, I am more interested about document order not live or static

Comment: @PK: All methods return nodes in tree order.

Comment: @Guffa - Where does it specify that HTMLCollection is not live? A quick test on getElementsByName suggests that it does return a live collection, at least on FF, Chrome and IE10.

Comment: [WhatWG DOM](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-collection) says that a HTMLCollection is a collection that "can be either live or static. Unless otherwise stated, a collection must be live". I can't find anywhere where it states that an API function returns a static collection.

Comment: ... except querySelectorAll